# Hooking up PLED cables to Arduino to indicate if PC is off or on

Tags: arduino

I am new to arduino, but I recently bought it for a project I am trying to do. Basically, I want the Arduino to act as a replacement power button switch on a PC. I've seen from other forums how to turn on and off the PC, but I was wondering if there was a way for the Arduino to tell the status of the PC. My initial thought since the power button on the PC has an LED that turns on when the PC is on and off when it is off, I could use the PLED front panel cables and hook it up to Pin 13 to use it the same way. I tried hooking PLED+ to Pin 13 and PLED- to ground but it didn't work. There was probably something wrong in the code, but I was wondering if this was even possible to begin with. For my project, I need to know the status of the PC in order to run if/else statements when the PC is off.

Comment: You would need to know how the motherboard even drives the LED. You don't know what voltage the motherboard outputs, or what series resistance is used, or if the resistance is on LED+ or LED- pin, and if the LED is also used as a blinking indicator for standby/sleep modes, you don't know if the LED+ or LED- is driven with a transistor or other device. But yes, it is definitely possible. All you know is that you can connect a LED directly, and you know the LED polarity. Some motherboards can also drive a bicolor LED. Blindly connecting wires may damage expensive motherboard or Arduino.

Comment: Measure the voltages to GND at both pins of the power LED in "on" and in "off" state. If there is no useful digital signal level, use an ADC channel to decide.